# Error building F#:"Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#

I have a file called BasicFunctions.fs which is used by Program.fs.
BasicFunctions.fs is definitely above Program.fs in the project so the order is correct. But I keep on getting this error:

**Error 1   Files in libraries or multiple-file applications must begin with a namespace or module declaration, e.g. 'namespace SomeNamespace.SubNamespace' or 'module SomeNamespace.SomeModule'. Only the last source file of an application may omit such a declaration.**

I am using VS 2013, with F# 3.1.
Here is the example code, nothing special:

BasicFunctions.fs

```
module BasicFunctions

let runAll = 
    let result = 4
    result
```

Program.fs

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    BasicFunctions.runAll        
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Here is the screenshot of the solution:

[image: VS Screenshot]

Comment: On which file do you get the error?

Comment: On  file Program.fs

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any more files after `Program.fs`? Is your project an "executable" or a "library"? Can you show the project?

Comment: Uploaded screenshot. It's a console application.

Comment: Have you verified that it's a console application? Maybe you have switched it accidentally? Is the indentation shown in `Program.fs` your actual indentation? What's in `BasicFunctions2.fs`?

Comment: Definitely still a console, indentation is correct. BasicFunctions2.fs the same code as BasicFunctions.fs just returns a 6 instead, and module name is BasicFunctions2

Comment: Could you show us the contents of your `.fsproj` file? The screenshot doesn't tell me what I need to know. I particularly want to see the contents of the `<ItemGroup>` element that includes the lines `<Compile Include="BasicFunctions.fs" />` and so on. If the `.fsproj` file is too long to paste in, then at least show us the entire contents of that particular `<ItemGroup>` element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the problem. There seems to be an issue when you copy and paste .fs files instead of creating a new file from scratch. Found this link using google:
https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/104

To resolve the issue I just deleted the two files BasicFunctions.fs and BasicFunctions2.fs and created them using the **"New Item.."** menu item in VS, also ensuring that they are before the main file Program.fs.

If you don't want the hassle of re-creating files, it would be better to actually modify the .fsproj file to ensure that Program.fs is the last file. Credit goes to **rmunn** in the comments section.

It's building successfully now, thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: This is why I asked to see your `.fsproj` file, though now that you've resolved the problem that's not necessary. I wanted to see if the `Program.fs` line was *really* the last line in the project file, the way Visual Studio thought it was. Turns out that it wasn't, and that's why you had the issue. Glad you were able to solve it independently!

Comment: Just reproduced the problem again, and indeed the file I copied and pasted is still below the Program.fs file in the .fsproj file, even though it's ordered correctly in the VS studio ui. I manually edited the project file, and now it works.